# Column names that match with observations in R

Tags: r

I have this data frame:

```
x <-c("jan_12", "feb_12", "apr_12",  "jan_12")
jan_12 <-c(0, NA, NA, 0)
feb_12 <-c(NA, 0, NA,0)
mar_12 <-c(1,0, NA, 1)
apr_12 <-c(0,0, 0, 1)
may_12 <-c(NA,0, 0, 0)
jun_12 <-c(NA,1, 1, NA)
df <- data.frame(x, jan_12, feb_12, mar_12, apr_12, may_12, jun_12, stringsAsFactors = F)
```

Every row represents a person who works in a bussines. The variable X is the date in which the person was hired. For example the first person was hired in January 2012 and so on. The other variables represent the month in which the person was paid (value 0) and was not paid (value 1). And I need to do the following:

To create a new binary variable with value 1 if the person was not paid in either of the two following month after his hiring.

How can I start? I tried  with dplyr and data table but I ended up with no solution.

```
[Edited: Notation of missing values: from "NA" to NA]
```

Comment: In my opinion this question doesn't belong here here but Stackoverflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Edited my answer based on your edits]

You can use apply:

```
df[,"x"] = as.character(df[,"x"]) # See comment 
apply(df, 1, function(X){ind = match(X['x'], names(X)); sum(as.numeric(X[ind:(ind+1)]), na.rm = T) != 0})
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

[comment]:
I would suggest using stringAsFactor = F as your populate your data frame, then you can omit the first line of code.

```
df <- data.frame(x, jan_12, feb_12, mar_12, apr_12, may_12, jun_12, stringsAsFactors = F)
```

Comment: Thanks, Yue.  I used your answer with as.factor(ifelse....) in order to create the binary variable. But I have a question: if for example in one of the two following months there is a "NA" value, the result of the apply command is NA ,too. Do you know how can I fix that and omit the NA's?

Comment: I tried to use na.rm=TRUE inside the sum function but  it seems to always return a FALSE value whenever there is a NA value in either one of the two following months.

Comment: I see where the problem is. I realize you are using "NA" in your question. With quotation you are only adding text "NA". Try using NA instead: eg. jan_12 <-c(0, NA, NA, 0) .  By doing this you also don't need as.numeric() anymore. Did your dataset come with "NA"?

Comment: Fixed. Also, I changed the first value of feb_12 to NA.

Comment: My dataset has missing values

Comment: I guess my question is, is your dataset come with NA as numeric values, or "NA" with quotation. If you are creating a data.frame by yourself, as you posted in the question, try stringsAsFactors = F. eg: df <- data.frame(x, jan_12, feb_12, mar_12, apr_12, may_12, jun_12, stringsAsFactors = F)

Comment: Edited. My dataset come with NA as numeric values.